# Switch в ToolBar. Как устранить nullPointerExeption?

Tags: android, toolbar

Получается я ссылаюсь на несуществующий объект? Как исправить?

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
Switch switch1;
Toolbar toolbar;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter2;
String[] _category = {"society", "science", "technics"};
int[] img_res = {R.drawable.man_black, R.drawable.category_add, R.drawable.televisor};
ArrayList<MenuItem> arrayList = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    recyclerAdapter2 = new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter2);

    int i = 0;
    for (int img : img_res) {
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(img, _category[i]);
        arrayList.add(menuItem);
        i++;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar, menu);

    // Switch switch1= (Switch)menu.findItem(R.id.action_switch).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.action_switch);
    // switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    android.view.MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.switch_toolbar);
    item.setActionView(R.layout.switcher);
    View actionView = item.getActionView();
    Switch mySwitch = (Switch) actionView.findViewById(R.id.switch_toolbar);
    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (android.view.MenuItem item) {
    int option_id = item.getItemId();
    if (option_id == R.id.add_word) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (option_id == R.id.delete_word) {
    }
    if (option_id == R.id.add_category) {
    }
    if (option_id == R.id.remove_category) {
    }
    if (option_id == R.id.switch_toolbar) {
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged (CompoundButton compoundButton,boolean b) {
    if (switch1.isChecked()) {
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    } else {
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Switch xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textOff="Ru"
    android:textOn="En"
    android:id="@+id/switch_layout"
    app:showText="true"
    android:theme="@style/SCBSwitch"
>
</android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat>
```

Menu XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/add_word"
        android:title="Add Word"
        android:icon="@drawable/plus_circle_black_on_white"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
    />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete_word"
        android:title="Delete Word"
        android:icon="@drawable/rounded_delete_button_with_minus"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
    />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/remove_category"
        android:title="Remove Category"
        android:icon="@drawable/category_remove"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:orderInCategory="400"
    />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add_category"
        android:title="Add Category"
        android:icon="@drawable/category_add"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:orderInCategory="300"
    />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/switch_toolbar"
        android:title="switcher"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/switcher"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:orderInCategory="500"
    />
</menu>
```

Comment: Перенесите инициализацию в onPrepareOptionsMenu

Comment: Та же ошибка. NullPointerExeption при попытке вызвать `setOnCheckedChangeListener`. Если убрать строку           `mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);` - приложение запускается

Answer (score 1):

```
Switch mySwitch = (Switch)actionView.findViewById(R.id.switch_toolbar);
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

Попробуйте вынести это в `onCreate()`, сразу после

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: В любых вариациях выдает  NullPointerExeption ссылаясь на эту строчку  `android.view.MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.switch_toolbar);`